# Get forbidden to send email with multiple recipients

Tags: sendgrid

I am facing a problem that when i send to multiple recipients (about 100), it response forbidden. But it was fine previously. And I have tested to send few recipients (about 3), it works fine.

May i know is that any change on free plan?
Many Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [free Sendgrid plan](https://sendgrid.com/pricing/) allows you to send up to 100 emails a day. If you are trying to send more than that 100th email in a day then you won't be able to and you should upgrade to a plan that supports more emails.

Comment: Hi Philnash, but I just send about 20 emails today, and it work perfectly before (with more than 100 recipients) . Is that one email with many recipients count as multiple email currently??

Comment: The pricing page says: "Every time you send one email to one recipient, it’s deducted as one email credit from your Email API plan.". The limit is a soft limit, but if you keep sending more emails eventually it will cut you off. If you are sending emails to hundreds of recipients per day then you likely need a new plan.

Comment: Thanks, i got it. Thanks again for your help